# Issue with section text assuming same color as body text

Tags: sectioning, color, document-classes

I am trying to understand a behavior where section headers assume the color of the first word in the section.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}    
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\makeatletter
\newcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{.25in}%
                                    {1.3ex \@plus .5ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                    {-.5em \@plus -.1em}%
                  {\reset@font\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother    
\begin{document}
\section{First}
{\color{red} Hello there} More text
\end{document}
```

The desired outcome is for "Hello there" to be red but the rest of the text (including "First") to be black. However, "First" is red. If a word is inserted before "{\color" then the desired behavior occurs. What is going on here? The answer must be some basic fact about latex that I don't know.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply use `\textcolor{red}{Hello there}`

Comment: Thanks--it works. Why does it behave this way?

Comment: No idea. Anyway, personally, I use the `titlesec` package for this sort of modifications to the defaults, and I don't think you'd have this sort of problem.

Comment: Without the negative vertical space the problem doesn't occur. (Just a debuging result to help you figuring out the problem... But I can't explain it... possibly this negative space says to latex to start coloring from the beginning of the line... If you knew a way to add the `#1` argument of the section inside the command you could possibly solve the problem -that is the "why?"-)

Comment: That is very interesting--definitely a useful lead.

Comment: In this case (3rd spacing is negative) the section head is inserted with `\everypar` which executed in horizontal mode i.e when TeX see H of Hello, so when color change was already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let say that the issue have nothing to do with the definition of `\section`. So the problem is not here, but in using `\color{red}...` 
instead of `\textcolor{red}{...}`.

Here is a MWE that replicate the issue

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{color}    

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Foo}
{\color{red}Bar} bla bla
\end{document}
```

Why?

When the fifth argument of `\@startsection` is negatif the heading is prepended to the paragraph of following text with the `\everypar` command.
The command `\everypar` is executed in horizontal mode i.e. when TeX see the character H in Hello, but at this moment is too late and the color change is already done. Here is another exemple

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{color}    

\begin{document}
\everypar{Foo \everypar{}}
{\color{red}\ifvmode\hrule\vskip1cm\fi Bar} bla bla
\end{document}
```

The solution is to use `\textcolor{red}{...}` or `\leavevmode{\color{red}...}`.